# Inspecting and visualizing gaps/blanks and structure in large dataframes

Tags: r, visualization

I have a large dataframe (400000 x 50) that I want to visually inspect for structure and blanks/gaps.

Is there an existing library or ggplot2 function, that can spit out a picture like this:

[image: Desired Output]

Where red might be "Dates", blue for "factors", green for "characters", and black for blanks/NAs.

Comment: `image(as.matrix(df))`

Comment: very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545423/visual-structure-of-a-data-frame-locations-of-nas-and-much-more

Comment: To get the  (top-down) row ordering to correspond with the dataframe, `image( t(X)[, (nrow(X):1)] )` where `X <- as.matrix( df )` ; but this won't color code the column-types.  One can adjust the background `bg` parameter of the plot and that will color the missing in the @Khashaa answer.

Comment: Hi, If you have 400 000 rows there is no way you could see a NA point or NA row on your 1280*1024 screen... I don't think that the "image" function allows you to increase the size of specific pixels. In the link posted by @Jeff in the previous comment i suggested applying `size <- 20 / log( prod(dim(DF)) )` to adapt the point size (ggplot) so we can see them. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `dfviewr` in `lasagnar` ?  The following reproduces the desired graphic for the 50 row x 10 column `df.in` in the package:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("swihart/lasagnar")
library(lasagnar)   
dfviewr(df=df.in)
## also try:
##dfviewr(df=df.in, legend=FALSE)
##dfviewr(df=df.in, gridlines=FALSE)
```

[image]

So, to be fair, `dfviewr` didn't exist at the time of the question, but to see some of the ideas that led to its development and how to actually visualize 400,000 rows, see the for-loop at the very bottom, and don't be too foolhardy and run the function on `df2.in` (400,000 x 50):

```
## Do not run:
## system.time(dfviewr(df=df2.in, gridlines=FALSE)) ## 10 minutes before useRaster=TRUE                                          
                                                    ##  2 minutes after
```

Also, `tabplot:::tableplot()` doesn't seem to support dates or characters:

```
library(tabplot)
tableplot(df.in)
```

produces:

`Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered,  : vmode 'character' not implemented`

and so we eliminate the character column (#9):

```
tableplot(df.in[,c(-9)])
```

which produces:

`Error in UseMethod("as.hi") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.hi' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')"`

so we eliminate the first column (Date) as well:

```
tableplot(df.in[,c(-1,-9)])
```

and get

[image]

And for the 400,000 by 50 `df2.in` without the Date or character columns, the image rendering was quite quick (6 seconds):

```
system.time(tableplot(df2.in[,c(-(1+seq(0,40,10)), -(9+seq(0,40,10))) ]))
```

[image]

### For the interested reader...

I present first a baby example on 50 rows, then an example on the 400,000 rows.

For what it's worth, I second the comment by @cmbarbu about visually looking at 400K rows on the same plot being limited by a screen that at best has 2K pixels in height, so some kind of breaking apart across pages might be beneficial to prevent overplotting.  I include an attempt at this breaking apart by making a PDF document with 400 rows in 1000 plots/pages.

I do not know of a function that will render the requested plot with a data.frame being an input.  My approach will make a matrix mask of the data.frame and then use `lasagna()` from the [`lasagnar` package on github](https://github.com/swihart/lasagnar).  `lasagna()` is a wrapper for the function `image( t(X)[, (nrow(X):1)] )` where `X` is a matrix.  This call reorders the rows so that they match the order of the data.frame, and the wrapper allows the ability to toggle grid lines and add legends (legend=TRUE will invoke `image.plot( t(X)[, (nrow(X):1)] )` -- however, in the example below I explicitly add a legend not using image.plot()).

### libraries for the task

```
library(fields)
library(colorspace)  
library(lubridate)
library(devtools)
install_github("swihart/lasagnar")
library(lasagnar)
```

### create a sample dataframe of 50 rows (baby example before 400K example)

```
df.in <- data.frame(date=seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'), 
                    by = '1 week'),
           col1=rnorm(50),
           col2=rnorm(50),
           col3=rnorm(50),
           col4=rnorm(50),
           col5=as.factor(c("A","B")),
           col6=as.factor(c("MS","PHD")),
           col7=rnorm(50),
           col8=(c("cherlene","randy")),
           col9=rnorm(50),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

### induce missingness

```
df.in[19:23  , 2:4  ] <- NA
df.in[c(7, 9),      ] <- NA
df.in[2:30   , 4    ] <- NA
df.in[10     , 7    ] <- NA
df.in[14     , 6:10 ] <- NA
```

### check structure

```
str(df.in)
```

### prep the mask matrix

```
mat.out <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(df.in), ncol=ncol(df.in))
```

### then cycle through columns for types; apply is.na() at the end

```
## red for dates
mat.out[,sapply(df.in,is.POSIXct)] <- 1
## blue for factors
mat.out[,sapply(df.in,is.factor)] <- 2
## green for characters
mat.out[,sapply(df.in,is.character)] <- 3
## white for numeric
mat.out[,sapply(df.in,is.numeric)] <- 4
## black for NA
mat.out[is.na(df.in)] <- 5
```

### row names might be nice for tracing back to the original data

```
row.names(mat.out) <- 1:nrow(df.in)
```

### render { lasagna(X) is a wrapper for image( t(X)[, (nrow(X):1)] ) }

```
lasagna(mat.out, col=c("red","blue","green","white","black"), 
        cex=0.67, main="")
```

[image]

### legends are possible:

```
lasagna(mat.out, col=c("red","blue","green","white","black"), 
        cex=.67, main="")
legend("bottom", fill=c("red","blue","green","white","black"),
        legend=c("dates", "factors", "characters", "numeric", "NA"), 
        horiz=T, xpd=NA, inset=c(-.15), border="black")
```

[image]

### turn gridlines off with gridlines=FALSE

```
lasagna(mat.out, col=c("red","blue","green","white","black"), 
        cex=.67, main="", gridlines=FALSE)
legend("bottom", fill=c("red","blue","green","white","black"),
        legend=c("dates", "factors", "characters", "numeric", "NA"), 
        horiz=T, xpd=NA, inset=c(-.15), border="black")
```

[image]

## Let's do an example of OP data size:  400,000 rows x 50 cols

### create a sample dataframe

```
df2.10 <- data.frame(date=seq(ymd('2012-04-07'),ymd('2013-03-22'), 
                    by = '1 week'),
           col1=rnorm(400000),
           col2=rnorm(400000),
           col3=rnorm(400000),
           col4=rnorm(400000),
           col5=as.factor(c("A","B")),
           col6=as.factor(c("MS","PHD")),
           col7=rnorm(400000),
           col8=(c("cherlene","randy")),
           col9=rnorm(400000),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

### induce missingness

```
df2.10[c(19:23), c(2:4)  ] <- NA
df2.10[c(7,  9),         ] <- NA
df2.10[c(2:30), 4        ] <- NA
df2.10[10     , 7        ] <- NA
df2.10[14     , c(6:10)  ] <- NA    
df2.10[c(450:750), ] <- NA
df2.10[c(399990:399999), ] <- NA
```

### cbind into 50 column wide df; check structure

```
df2.in <- cbind(df2.10, df2.10, df2.10, df2.10, df2.10)
str(df2.in)
```

### prep the mask matrix

```
mat.out <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(df2.in), ncol=ncol(df2.in))
```

### then cycle through columns for types; apply is.na() at the end

```
## red for dates
mat.out[,sapply(df2.in,is.POSIXct)] <- 1
## blue for factors
mat.out[,sapply(df2.in,is.factor)] <- 2
## green for characters
mat.out[,sapply(df2.in,is.character)] <- 3
## white for numeric
mat.out[,sapply(df2.in,is.numeric)] <- 4
## black for NA
mat.out[is.na(df2.in)] <- 5
```

### row names might be nice for tracing back to the original data

```
row.names(mat.out) <- 1:nrow(df2.in)
```

### render { lasagna_plain(X) has no gridelines or rownames }

```
pdf("pages1000.pdf")
  system.time(
    for(i in 1:1000){
        lasagna_plain(mat.out[((i-1)*400+1):(400*i),],
                      col=c("red","blue","green","white","black"), cex=1, 
                      main=paste0("rows: ", (i-1)*400+1,  " - ",  (400*i)))
    }
  )
dev.off()
```

The for-loop completed 40 seconds on my machine, and the PDF very shortly thereafter.  Now just page down after standardizing the page size in the PDF viewer, viewing pages/plots such as these:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: impressive. You should add `set.seed()` before you make that test data set so your results are reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip!  I changed the example in the post; as well as saved df.in (50 rows x 10 columns) and df2.in (400,000 rows x 50 columns) in the `lasagnar` package in the name of reproducibility.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at the `tabplot` package. With such a big `data.frame` it will take a while to load, but it should also correctly identify missing values. More info [here](http://www.ancienteco.com/2012/05/quickly-visualize-your-whole-dataset.html).

Here's an image example using the diamond `data.frame`.

[image: tabplot_diamonds]

**EDIT**

I just saw that you said your df has 50 columns. I've used tabplot on df's that size and find the resolution of information limited by the screen breadth. The row count can also be an issue, but I personally find more information is lost if the df is too wide. Thus, may I suggest you parse it into 3 separate df (for example using `dplyr`) and then run them through the `tableplot()` function of `tabplot` or similar.

Comment: `tableplot()` threw an error when I tried a dataset with column-types `Date` and/or `character` (see my post for the errors).  Do you know of a fix aside from changing the column-type to factors or numbers?

Comment: Actually never worked with df that had dates in it and surprised at the error on characters. I would've done exactly the same as you, had it thrown that error to me though, so the simple answer is no. Also checked the help files and couldn't find anything useful. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot.

```
require(Amelia)
data(freetrade)
missmap(freetrade)
```

It won't do the red, blue green, but it gets your grid. I'd also give the VIM package a shot as it provides numerous options for visualizing missing data.

http://www.statistik.tuwien.ac.at/forschung/CS/CS-2008-1complete.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the blank/gaps you are talking about are missing values (NA)

`image(t(as.matrix(is.na(df))))`

Comment: Taking forever to render... I was imagining that there was a specific library/package that did this.

Comment: I do not see any faster solution. Try to plot directly to a file (pdf, png) and not on an X11 window. That speeds thing up

Comment: This only took around a minute to render on my windows machine, `x <- replicate(400000, rbinom(50,1,0.01));x[x == 1] = NA;image(as.matrix(is.na(x)))`.

Comment: And how are you going to review 400000 rows visually on a screen that has max a couple thousands pixels?

Comment: the `useRaster=TRUE` argument to `image()` can speed things up a lot

Comment: To get the  (top-down) row ordering to correspond with the dataframe, `image( t(X)[, (nrow(X):1)] )` where `X <- as.matrix( is.na(df) )` ; but this won't color code the column-types.