# Inspect a large dataframe for errors arising during merge/combine in python

Tags: python, pandas, inspection, fuzzywuzzy

I hope this is an appropriate question for here. If not, let me know, and I will remove it immediately.

Question:

How can I use python to inspect (visually?) a large dataset for errors that arise during combination?

Background:

I am working with several large (but not, you know "Big") datasets that I combine to form one larger dataset. This new set is ~2.5G in size, so it does not fit in most spreadsheet programs, or at least not in the ones I've tried (MS Excel, OpenOffice).

The process to create the final dataset uses fuzzy matching (via `fuzzywuzzy`), and I want to inspect the results of the matching to see if there are any errors introduced.

As of now, I have tried importing the entire set into a `pandas` dataframe. This DF has 64 columns, so when I simply do something like `df.head()` the resulting displayed info obviously does not show all the columns; I thus ruled out just iterating through multiple `.head()` calls.

There is a similar question about visualizing specific aspects of a dataframe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813057/inspecting-and-visualizing-gaps-blanks-and-structure-in-large-dataframes). My question is different, I think, because I don't need to visualize anything about the underlying structure or types. I just want to visually inspect areas I suspect might have errors.

Comment: How about setting the display properties so that you can display all rows and columns? Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the thought! I have tried that, but on a standard screen inside an IDE (I use PyCharm) there are wrapping issues, and I'd like to inspect 10-12 of those columns at a time.

Another approach that I can't seem to get to work right now is to make each row a list, then print the list out in a descending fashion on screen, so I can at least read down the "row" to see if things are looking good. I think this might work because each item of the list would be printed on its own line on-screen, so I'd have a lot of screen space.

Comment: I think you probably just need to spend some time with indexing/selection docs:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/indexing.html  Then you can, for example, look at the first five columns of data where a certain column begins with the letter "W".  If there are specific things you have trouble doing, then post a new  followup question about how to do it.

Comment: Henry, if you're looking at only 10-12 rows at a time... I suggest transposing so that your 60 columns end up as index and vice versa. That should work nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about slicing your 10-12 rows and then transposing that you have a 64 rows x 12 columns dataframe. This should be readable provided you don't have very large index names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set max number of rows, 64 would be enough here but I'm trying to be safe
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,64))
nstart = 100
# Slice 12 lines starting at nstart, and transpose that...
df.iloc[nstart:(nstart+13)].T
```

I'm sparing you the output here, but try running the above code.

Comment: Much appreciated. I think this is the way to go. Wasn't ware of the `.iloc` feature.

Comment: `.ix` accepts mixed integer/label based indexing should you need it.If my answer solved your question please mark the answer as accepted in order to close the question